# Security flaws while storing auto-login token

Tags: authentication, javascript, token

I must to accomplish auto-login with a token on my website. Token is generated on back-end, on front-end (Single-Page Application) I have to store token in secure way.

I'm using secured channels (HTTPS and WSS).

*Could you please suppose security flaws / attack vectors in next cases*:

1. Store token as global variable (accessible from console), without encryption;
2. Store token as local variable, without encryption;
3. Store token in local storage, without encryption;
4. Store token in local storage with encryption.

*What are the best practices to store token for my needs?*

Comment: WSS = Secure Web Sockets? And is there a reason that you don't simply use cookies? And what do you mean by storing the token securely? Do you want to forbid the client from seeing their own token?

Comment: @tim yes, that's Secure Web Sockets. I'm going to use local storage, which has the same security level as cookies. I want forbid everyone except client to see the token. As I understand there are attacks which can steal cookies, right?